# Notify with confirmation in C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, stl

I have some loop that runs in parallel and has these lines:

```
std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock(_condLoopMutex);
_condLoopCondition.wait(lock, [this]() { return _conditionReady || _condLoopStopped; });
_conditionReady = false;

// DO SOMETHING
```

The boolean variable

```
_conditionReady
```

is set in parallel thread by means of the following construction:

```
_conditionReady = true;
_condLoopCondition.notify_one();
```

However, sometimes my program freezes. It seems that notification comes between function 'wait' passes arguments and checks '_conditionReady' variable.

To avoid this, I implemented the following:

```
while (_conditionReady && !_condLoopStopped)
    {
        _condLoopCondition.notify_one();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(100));
    }
```

So that it keeps notifying until

```
_conditionReady == false
```

which means that wait is over.

Is this the only solution of this problem - renotifying until wait is over? Is there any other regular method of handling these issues?

Comment: You should be holding the mutex while setting your `_conditionReady` variable. Also, `sleep` is **never** a solution.

Comment: you can also synchronize via std::atomic<>. It may simplify your code a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to hold the mutex when you modify your `_conditionReady` variable. This avoids the race condition by ensuring that the variable is not modified between checking its value and starting wait. Make sure you release the mutex before or after calling `notify_one` to allow your waiting thread to wakeup (if you do it after calling notify you can introduce a small performance penalty by waking up the waiting thread and it then immediately going back to sleep as the mutex is locked before waking a second time when the mutex is unlocked). e.g.:

```
{
  std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock(_condLoopMutex);
  _conditionReady = true;
}
_condLoopCondition.notify_one();
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, **sleep** is never a solution for bugs. It should really generate a compiler warning everytime it is used, which would convey the same message.

Now, whenever you modify a control variable which is guarded by condition, it should be done while holding a mutex - usually same one which is used in your `cond.wait()`. Your code doesn't do this.